# Ubuntu 14.10 - udev refuses to update

Tags: upgrade, updates, 14.10, udev

On Ubuntu 14.10 Udev refuses to update.

I executed this code:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Which gave this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
udev : Depends: libudev1 (= 208-8ubuntu8.1) but 208-8ubuntu8.2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

So I then did:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Which output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
udev
The following packages will be upgraded:
udev
1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 40 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/804 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,096 B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 176972 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../udev_208-8ubuntu8.2_amd64.deb ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_208-8ubuntu8.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
fgets gave an empty string from `/var/lib/dpkg/info/udev.triggers'
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/udev_208-8ubuntu8.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I then tried to:

```
sudo apt-get install udev
```

Which gave this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
udev
1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 40 not to upgrade.
Need to get 804 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,096 B disk space will be freed.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates/main udev amd64 208-8ubuntu8.2 
[804 kB]
Fetched 804 kB in 0s (873 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 176972 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../udev_208-8ubuntu8.2_amd64.deb ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_208-8ubuntu8.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
fgets gave an empty string from `/var/lib/dpkg/info/udev.triggers'
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/udev_208-8ubuntu8.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Did this several times, even deleting the **.deb** package and forcing a redownload of the package, in case it was a bad d/l, had the same effect!

Then tried;

**Synaptic**

```
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_208-8ubuntu8.2_amd64.deb:
fgets gave an empty string from `/var/lib/dpkg/info/udev.triggers'
```

and thus;

```
(synaptic:3584): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_child_watch_add_full: assertion 'pid > 0' failed
(Reading database ... 176972 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../udev_208-8ubuntu8.2_amd64.deb ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_208-8ubuntu8.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
fgets gave an empty string from `/var/lib/dpkg/info/udev.triggers'
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_208-8ubuntu8.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usrReading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:    
udev    
1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 40 not to upgrade.
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives//bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
```

Which stops me in my tracks!

Now what?

Comment: Did you do `sudo apt-get update` first?  It won't know if the .2 version exists if the apt repo data it had is out of date.

Comment: **sudo apt-get update**? Of course. It made no difference. The same error resulted _EVERY_ time.

Comment: Have you tried to manually delete the offending file so it gets downloaded again???  `sudo rm --force /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_208-8ubuntu8.2_amd64.deb`  Drop me a note @Fabby on the outcome...

Comment: Several times...as stated in the above description. ALWAYS gives the SAME (--unpack) dpkg error. Starting to think the original file is corrupted on the server? Is that even possible?

Answer (score -1):

Run:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all --install /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_208-8ubuntu8.2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: And that will not remove all the dependencies... like video card and keyboard?